# Deployment Icon

Tags: java, netbeans, icons

How can I get my icon to appear when I install a "clean and build" result?

My Netbeans 7 platform application runs OK but has the Netbeans box for an icon.   I have defined all the icons specified in the "branding literature" and none of them get used for the "clickable exe".  They do show up on the top component windows.

Comment: It's doable, is wat I know!

Comment: Does the Jar produce a Swing based GUI?

Comment: Still no answer for this after two years? Are you kidding me?

Comment: I found an answer to this question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683335/including-an-icon-into-a-self-contained-javafx-application-exe