# including an icon into a self-contained JavaFX application (.exe)

Tags: installation, icons, native, javafx-2

Followed the instructions [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_cookbook_using_drop) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm). I am using **JDK 7u9** and **NetBeans 7.2.1**. What I did was create the whole path relative to my project's root folder (*C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\icotest\package\windows\icotest.ico*). I tried both with a 48x48 and a 256x256 size. Here's a tree overview for my *project* called **icotest**:

```
│   build.xml
│   manifest.mf
│
├───build
│   │   built-jar.properties
│   │
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───icotest
│   │           Main$1.class
│   │           Main.class
│   │
│   ├───empty
│   └───generated-sources
│       └───ap-source-output
├───dist
│   │   icotest.html
│   │   icotest.jar
│   │   icotest.jnlp
│   │
│   └───web-files
│           dtjava.js
│           error.png
│           get_java.png
│           get_javafx.png
│           javafx-chrome.png
│           javafx-loading-100x100.gif
│           javafx-loading-25x25.gif
│           upgrade_java.png
│           upgrade_javafx.png
│
├───nbproject
│   │   build-impl.xml
│   │   genfiles.properties
│   │   jfx-impl.xml
│   │   project.properties
│   │   project.xml
│   │
│   ├───configs
│   │       Run_as_WebStart.properties
│   │       Run_in_Browser.properties
│   │
│   └───private
│       │   private.properties
│       │   private.xml
│       │
│       └───configs
│               Run_as_WebStart.properties
│               Run_in_Browser.properties
│
├───package
│   └───windows
│           icotest.ico
│
└───src
    └───icotest
            Main.java
```

This is what **build.xml** looks like:

> ```
> <target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
>     <fx:deploy verbose="true" nativeBundles="exe" outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
>         <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
>         <fx:resources>
>             <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
>             <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
>         </fx:resources>
>         <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
>         <fx:preferences shortcut="true"/>
>     </fx:deploy>
> </target>
> ```

No matter what I do - I still get this message during the **dist build** process (that activates **ISS**) with the **debug** flag set to **true** in the according **build.xml** file: "Using default package resource [application icon] (add package/windows/icotest.ico to the class path to customize)"

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: This person on the Oracle JavaFX forum seems to have the same issue.  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10699476#10699476

Comment: Thanks for the link - that has confirmed that the official tutorial is slightly off and other people are having the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the **answer** [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2471480). It appears that the guidelines posted on the Oracle's website are currently mismatching the actual deployment scenarios available. Namely, when dealing with *NetBeans*, **ant** is unaware of the current directory that is presumed to be your root project. As it has been suggested in the according forum thread - simply add the directory containing *"package/windows/${projectname}.ico"* to **ant**'s classpath and it will pick up the relevant resource, even though the tutorial claims that this should happen automatically due to the existing (**?**) addition of **'.'** to the build script.

[image: todo]

Comment: How to acheive same thing with maven in eclipse??

Comment: Even this is an old post, but there is a problem with this type of solution. What if you have more than one project to build? Should the classpath fit to all projects? The answer is NO! If you would like to make the Netbeans internal Ant be aware of the given classpath in build.xml or includes files, you have to put in properties `build.sysclasspath=last`, then you be fully responsible for setting the correct classpath in build.xml and include files. This was discussed in 2001 already here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9527

Answer (score 16):

After trial and error and using XXL answer i post a more clear way of adding your custom icon into a JavaFX self contained. By the way am using Netbeans 7.3 JDK 1.7u17
1. Begin with creating a folder named package inside the folder(has the same name as your project) found in your project src directory.

[image: win]
2. under the folder package, create the folder windows and this is where you will place your custom icon.please ensure the name of your .ico file is the same as the application name
[image]
 Note: this could have easily be done in netbeans by creating a new package but for some reason, netbeans does not allow your to name a new package 'package'
[image]

3. Next your add the directory containing /package/windows/.ico to Ant clathpath properties
   [image]
4. Clean & Build your project and the final output will look something like this with your custom icon
   [image]

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar and I love you for this and wish I'd found it before I'd asked the same question. Nevertheless, I shall link this answer to my own question such that anyone else who can't properly phrase a question may by chance stumble upon this eloquent and effective solution. To you I tip my hat, and I bid you a fine day.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I repeated these steps for Mac OS X, changing `mediaplayer/package/windows` into `mediaplayer/package/macosx`, but still failed to get the icon into the package. As a workaround, the default icon gets included into the app package's `resource` folder, and can be replaced manually.

Comment: For Mac OS X, you have to create an .icns file (e.g. MyApp.icns).

Comment: For those of you using E(fx)clipse the classpath mentioned above can be set when you right click on build.xml and select Ant Build... (with the three dots).   Finally got my icons appearing.    Also, debugging can be turned on when first clicking on build.fxbuild turning on the Enable Verbose Build Mode