# Changing Ants Task Classpath From Command Line

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx

I'm trying to build a javafxpackager project similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683335/including-an-icon-into-a-self-contained-javafx-application-exe) issue which actually solves my problem via NetBeans. However, I would like to automate the task without using NetBeans.

Unfortunately it seems that in order to get this to work I need to change the classpath that Ant uses for its own execution (not the one it uses to compile my stuff). I can hardcode my directories (which is a problem for my case) or change the ant.bat file probably (again a problem).

Ideally I'd like to know if there is an ant configuration or command line that allows me to append a directory to its internal path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ant comes with the `-lib` command line parameter:

```
ant -lib /home/ant/extras
```

runs Ant picking up additional task and support jars from the /home/ant/extras location

[Reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html)

Comment: Thanks! SO is blocking me from awarding the bounty but I'll do that when its enabled.