# The ability to add an icon to a jar file

Tags: java, javafx

I've been looking around on how to change the default Java "coffee cup" icon of the executable jar file and the way to do it, I've found, is:

```
getFrame().setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass()
.getClassLoader().getResource("MyProject/resources/myIcon.png")));
```

***OR:***

```
this.getFrame().setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("plagialyzer/resources/PlagiaLyzerIcon.png")));
```

I can't figure out how to add this into my **JavaFx classes**. Could anyone please point me on how to add this to, for example, the class below:

```
public class WakiliProject extends Application {

    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        ScreensController mainContainer = new ScreensController();

        Group root = new Group();

        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(mainContainer);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 624);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/MediaTools/antibanner.png"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Wakili");

        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the icon of your file, you could try this tutorial http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part7/

If you have >= 7u10 running, you could also try this (it's rather short): Adding an `<fx:icon >` element, like it's explained [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#7).

```
<fx:deploy ...> 
     <fx:info> 
         <fx:icon href="default.png"/> 
     </fx:info> 
     ... 
</fx:deploy>
```

In case you are running 7u9 or lower, you can follow this post and answer to achieve your goal: [including an icon into a self-contained JavaFX application (.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683335/including-an-icon-into-a-self-contained-javafx-application-exe)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. Does this go into the FXML or hibernate.cfg.xml? I'm using NetBeans

Comment: This goes into your build.xml

Comment: btw, a nice answer would be self-contained, not with external dependency links.. also a way to modify the normally executable self-contained.jar file with external packages would be the best (not even javafx).