# How do I customize the program name in a traybar notification in AWT?

Tags: java, notifications, awt

AWT's `TrayIcon` class has a method called [`displayMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType)) that shows a native OS message that in Windows 10 looks like this:

[image]

when called like this:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/isotype.png"));
final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, appName());
trayIcon.displayMessage("Caption", "Text text text", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

How do I customize the string "Java(TM) Platform SE binary". When I build a self-contained exe for my application, it instead reads "Blah.exe" while I'd prefer it if reads just "Blah".

To package the application I'm using the JavaFX toolchain through the excellent [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin).

Comment: Use [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) Cross-platform Java executable wrapper (a custom launcher)

Comment: @aKilleR: that means changing my whole installer toolchain. What do I gain by using launch4j?

Comment: @Pablo, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683335/including-an-icon-into-a-self-contained-javafx-application-exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround is to use `TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE`. In this case you won't get the last line at all, but you won't get any *INFO*, *WARNING* or *ERROR* icon either.

But the good thing is that **you can get your application icon in the displayed message**. If you create the `TrayIcon` with some image like `TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tooltip")` and then package your application with [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin), `displayMessage` method will reuse this image and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm actually getting the icon of my application in there, a small version, but it looks good; so, so far, this seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @Pablo You will still get your application icon in the system tray. I just meant that the round info icon will disappear

Comment: Yes, the round icon is gone, but my apps icon appear in the notification: https://i.imgur.com/uvcFT6i.png

Comment: I don't know, it just happened like that. My guess is that it's because that's the tray icon I created and it's re-using it.

Comment: Essentially doing this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

Answer (score 3):

On my system (tried both Java 8u151 and Java 9.0.1 on Windows 10), with the minimal setup of `build.gradle` from [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin), I have not found any configuration option for that name, but I can *control* it: *the packager simply takes the name of parent directory that contains my sources*.

Example with "Foo Bar":
Executable name = "FooBar.exe"
Displayed name = "Foo Bar"
[image]

(What I don't get, then, is why you see "Blah.exe" instead of the name of your parent directory...)

Answer (score 2):

To change the pop-up text which in your posted screenshot is displayed as `Java(TM) Platform SE binary` in your `Blah.exe` to `Blah` you could use for example the [Resource Hacker™](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Change in the section `Version Info` the value for `FileDescription` to `Blah` either interactive in the GUI or on commandline.

Find below a simple example which needs to be amended for your needs.

**versioninfo.rc** resource script containing the information for the [VERSIONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) resource

```
1 VERSIONINFO
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "00000409"
    {
        VALUE "FileDescription", "Blah"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0000 0x0409
}
}
```

**compile** the resource script to a resource file

```
ResourceHacker.exe -open versioninfo.rc \
    -save versioninfo.res \
    -action compile 
    -log CONSOLE
```

**add** the resource to the executable

```
ResourceHacker.exe -open Blah.exe \
    -save Blah_new.exe \
    -resource versioninfo.res \
    -action addoverwrite \
    -mask VERSIONINFO,1,0 \
    -log CONSOLE
```

For completeness here the command to extract the `VERSIONINFO` from an EXE file.

```
 ResourceHacker.exe -open Blah.exe \
     -save versioninfo.rc \
     -action extract \
     -mask VERSIONINFO,, \
     -log CONSOLE
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I cannot do anything to the .exe because in my build chain, creating the .exe and packaging it in the installer is an atomic operation (that's how javafxpackager works, which is what JavaFX-Gradle-plugin uses).

Comment: @Pablo As far as I know the `javafxpackager` doesn't create an `exe` file. The Gradle plugin uses `Inno Setup` (for EXE installers) or `WiX` (for MSI installers).

Comment: Fair enough, it's the plug in that makes it an atomic operation and not javafxpackager.

Comment: @Pablo Would you mind to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Based on the answer of [@Hugues M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6730571/hugues-m) it seems not to be the default behaviour. When I build the `minimal-setup-jfxnative` example provided by the `JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin` the created `exe` file does not even contain a `FileDescription` value. And the text `Java(TM) Platform SE binary`, in your screenshot, is comming from the `java.exe / javaw.exe` executable. So it would be interesting to reproduce your observed behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of TrayIcon is platform dependent. On a Mac, there's no such thing as "Java(TM) Platform SE binary", nor the executable.

If you want to change the behaviour on your platform, I guess you could play with awt.toolkit. See 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getDefaultToolkit--

Comment: I don't see anything in there that allows me to modify that name.